# Find all functions f such that $f(f(x))=f(x)+x$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, functional-equations

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that
>   $f(f(x))=f(x)+x, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. Find all such functions $f$.

Clearly, $f$ is an "one-to-one function". I have tried setting where $x\rightarrow f(x)$ so: $f(f(f(x)))=f(f(x))+f(x)=2f(x)+x$.

Also, from the original relation, we get that: $f(f(f(x)))=f(f(x)+x)$.

Equating the RHS of the last two relations we get that: $f(f(x)+x)=2f(x)+x$.

Probably to exploit the 1-1 we need a relation of the form $f(f(x))=f(\cdots)$.

I don't know how to carry this further... Any hint?

Comment: I don't think that the given condition is enough to provide only "nice" solutions. But clearly, $f(x)=\varphi x$ and $f(x)=-\frac{1}{\varphi}x$ are solutions.

Comment: Do we want to suppose that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom How will that help?

Comment: @Jason it will help because (assuming the axiom of choice) there are a *lot* of crazy discontinuous solutions.

Comment: @Jason in particular, we have a lot of $\Bbb Q$-linear functions.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Let's suppose that it is continuous $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is continuous and bijective... I claim either $f(x) = \phi x$ for all $x$, or $f(x) =-x/\phi$ for all $x$.  Here $\phi=(1+\sqrt{5})/2$.

We use the Fibonacci numbers $F_n$:
$$
F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n,\qquad F_0=0,\qquad F_1=1 .
\tag{1}$$
With $F_{-n}=(-1)^{n+1}F_n$, the recurrence holds for all integers, positive and negative.  And of course
$$
F_n = \frac{\phi^n+(-\phi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}}
\tag{2}$$

We assume $f$ is continuous and bijective.  And satisfies
$$
f(f(x)) = f(x) + x
\tag{3}$$
Proved in another answer: $f(0)=0$.
So $f$ is either increasing or decreasing.  Let's consider the increasing case.  So $f$ sends positive to positive and negative to negative.
I claim $f(x) = \phi x$ for all $x$.
Let $a > 0$, $f(a)=b$. (The case $a<0$ is below.)  We will show $b = \phi a$.

Starting with $f(a)=b$, we get by induction using (1) and (3):
$$
f(F_{k-1}a+F_{k}b)=F_{k}a+F_{k+1}b
\tag{4}$$
for all $k \ge 0$.  And applying
(1), (3) backward, we get (4)
for negative $k$ also.  (We **assumed** $f$ is bijective, so we
can go backward in (3).)

Since this is the increasing case, we have $b=f(a)>0$ since $a>0$.
For $k>0$ consider the negative values $-k$:
$$
f(F_{-k-1}a+F_{-k}b)=F_{-k}a+F_{-k+1}b
\\
f\big((-1)^kF_{k+1}a+(-1)^{k+1}F_{k}b\big)
=(-1)^{k+1}F_{k}a+(-1)^kF_{k-1}b
$$
What is the sign of $v_{-k}=(-1)^kF_{k+1}a+(-1)^{k+1}F_{k}b$ ?  If $b/a > \phi$,then by (2) the sign is $(-1)^{k+1}$ for large $k$.  So $f$ sends positive to negative and negative to positive for these values $v_{-k}$.  Similarly, if $b/a<\phi$, then the sign of $v_{-k}$ is $(-1)^k$ for large $k$, and again $f$ sends positive to negative and negative to positive for these values $v_{-k}$. Since this is impossible, we conclude $b/a=\phi$.

For case $a<0$, we have $b<0$.  Again we get negative to positive and positive to negative for $v_{-k}$ with $k$ large.

Now consider the decreasing case.  I claim $f(x) = -x/\phi$ for all $x$.  We still get (4).  But now $f$ is supposed to send positive to negative and negative to positive.  This time we get our contradictions by considering $v_k$ for large positive $k$ in (4).

Comment: There's no need to *assume* surjectivity. Injectivity follows readily and your $(4)$ for $a,b>0$ shows (using continuity) that $[0,\infty)$ is in the image. As $x\mapsto-f(-x)$ also has the given property, we *conclude* that also $(-\infty,0]$ is in the image. (This also shows we need only consider $a>0$)

Comment: OK, how to prove surjective in the decreasing case?

Answer (score 6):

> **Claim:** $f(0)=0$.

Assume $f(0) = k\neq 0 $, then $f(k)=f(k)+k$, a contradiction.

> **Claim:** If $f(x)$ is an analytic function, $f(x)=\phi x$ or $f(x)=-x/\phi$.

If $f$ is an analytic function, it has a unique polynomial expansion with zero constant term, i.e. $f(x) = a_1x+a_2x^2 +\cdots$. Then by comparing powers we get that:
$$a_1=\phi, -1/\phi$$
And all other powers are zero.

If $f(x)$ is not analytic, I'm not sure what else can be said about it.

Comment: Great thought! Can you elaborate on "comparing powers"?

Comment: @Jason - Just write out $f=a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \ldots$, and compare powers of $f(f(x)-f(x)-x=0$ which all should be zero.

Comment: If $f(0)=k,$ then $f(f(0))=f(k)=f(0)+0=k$. How did you get your first line? This implies $f(0)=f(k)$ or $k=0$ by injectivity.

Comment: Knowing that f is continuous and bijective thus monotone, can we prove that f is analytic?

Answer (score 6):

For each number $x\in[1,\phi)$, let either 
$$f(x)=\phi x,f(-x)=-\phi x\text{ or else }\\f(x)=-x/\phi,f(-x)=x/\phi$$
The choice is independent for each $x$ in that interval.  Then, for all other numbers, $f(x\phi^k)=f(x)\phi^k$.
For each ladder $x\phi^{-2},x\phi^{-1},x,x\phi,x\phi^2,...$, $f$ consistently shifts numbers up the scale, or down the scale.

Comment: That is not all the functions, correct?

Comment: I don't know.  There may be a way to define $f(x)$ arbitrarily over an interval, then use the function definition to extend it over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Is there another way to break the reals into disjoint sequences $a_k\phi^n+b_k(-\phi)^{-n}$?

Answer (score 1):

Pick a Hamel basis $(v_i)_{i\in I}$ for $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$. Group the basis vectors in pairs $(v_i,v_j)$ and on $v_i\mathbb Q+v_j\mathbb Q$ let $f$ be given (with respect to the basis $(v_1,v_2)$)  by the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$. As $A^2=A+1$, $f$ has the desired property. In other words: Find $J\subset I$ with $|J|=|I\setminus J|$ and a bijection $h\colon J\to I\setminus J$ and then let $f(\sum_{i\in I} q_iv_i)=\sum_{i\in J}((q_i+q_{h(i)})v_{h(i)}+q_{h(i)}v_i)$ (those are sums, not series!)

Comment: These should be all $\mathbb Q$-linear solutions. My solution set overlaps with @Michael's, but neither solution set  is *contained* in the other.